# how to resolve threadid=3: spin on suspend #1 threadid=2 (pcf=0)

Tags: android, listview

I have 310 items to be added in ListView,I have added in ListView using Base Adapter and successfully adding in ListView.

But when I scroll down the ListView , application is getting hanged, and in LogCat error is showing

```
04-11 17:30:57.581: W/dalvikvm(14868): threadid=3: spin on suspend #1 threadid=2 (pcf=0)
```

I have already spent my whole day in resolving this, but didnt succeeded.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been solved .

problem was there were multiple threads running thats why application got dead lock, `there was not problem of ListView or Adapter`.

Answer (score 0):

- Use view holder to prevent loading your `ListView` items in every scroll.
- Try not to use context mapping in your adapter. Pass your variables directly using constructor instead reading them over context in each view update.

Please check this article: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html